# Finding convergence zone/range for $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n^2}}{n(n+1)}$$

I used the ratio test and I end up with:

$$|x|*\frac{n}{n+2}$$

What steps do I need to take to continue?

Looking for hints or steps, not full solution/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you notice the powers of $\;x\;$ are *not* consecutive? They are $\;1,4,9,16,...\;$ , so the actual coefficients are

$$a_n:=\begin{cases}\cfrac1{\sqrt{n(n+1)}},\,&n\;\text{is a square}\\{}\\0,\,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

and thus

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}}=1$$

and thus the convergence radius is $\;1\;$ .

Comment: Shouldn't $a_n$ be the coefficient rather than the power?

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife Thank you, of course you're right. I completely missed the coefficients in the **actual** question and instead, for some joke my mind made to me, I saw a$\;x^{n^2}n^2\;$ instead of the actual $\;\frac{x^{n^2}}{n(n-1)}\;$ ...! The answer's the same, though. Editing now.

Answer (score 2):

Define 
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}0,\;\text{if n is not a perfect sqaure}\\
{1\over n+\sqrt{n}}, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
Your series is 
$$
\sum_{n}a_nx^n
$$
Now
$$
\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over\sqrt[n]{n+\sqrt n}}
$$
Last hint:
$$n\le n+\sqrt n\le 2n$$